# Http POST request in python using Klein for accessing json content

Tags: python-2.7, klein-mvc

I needed to POST a dictionary using Klein

from klein import Klein

import json

app = Klein()

dictionaries=[]

@app.route('/dict',methods=['POST'])

@inlineCallbacks

def pg_root():

```
dictionary = {'key' :request.json['name']}

dictionaries.append(dictionary)

return jsonify({'dictionaries': dictionary})
```

app.run("localhost",8080)

I dont think the funtion jsonify works here in klein. Please find an alternative.